# Solving coupled equations

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I am trying to solve two coupled equations in a one by one square (2 dimension). My code is as below:

```
sol = NDSolve[{2 D[b[x, y], x, x] + 2 D[b[x, y], y, y] + b[x, y] (D[c[x, y], x, x]
    + 2 D[c[x, y], y, y]) + 30 b[x, y] c[x, y] - 10 b[x, y] + D[b[x, y], x] D[c[x, y], x]
    + D[b[x, y], y] D[c[x, y], y] == 0,
    0.2 D[c[x, y], x, x] + 2 D[c[x, y],y, y] - b[x, y] c[x, y] == 0, 
    c[1, y] == 0.1, Derivative[1, 0][c][0, y] == 0, 
    Derivative[1, 0][b][0, y] == 0, Derivative[1, 0][b][1, y] == 0, 
    Derivative[0, 1][c][x, 0] == 0, Derivative[0, 1][c][x, 1] == 0,
    Derivative[0, 1][b][x, 0] == 0, Derivative[0, 1][b][x, 1] == 0},
    {b, c}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

The error is:

> Nonlinear coefficients are not supported in this version of NDSolve

could any one help me to these equations?  ​ ​

Comment: You have numerous syntax errors like, for example,  `+ + ` or `{Grad[c[x, y]} , {x, y}]`. Apart of their correction it appears that your equations are nonlinear, of the type that is not accessible for Mma yet.

Comment: Code can be submitted by highlighting it and checking the `{}` button.

Comment: Thank you both. I correct that mistakes. But a new problem happened. Do you know how can solve it?